# Classe em Delphi com campo opcional do tipo inteiro

Tags: delphi, soap, interface, wsdl, nullable

A dúvida é: como devo construir a minha classe TPESSOA de forma que o campo _id_cidade possa ser nulo.

Banco de dados

```
Create Table PESSOA (
ID  INTEGER NOT NULL, 
NOME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
ID_CIDADE INTEGER)
```

No Dephi

```
  TPESSOA = Class(TRemotable)
  private
        _id : Integer;
        _Nome: String;
        _id_cidade : integer;
    procedure Set_id_cidade(const Value: Integer);
    function Get_id_cidade: integer;
  published
        property id : Integer read _id write _id;
        property Nome : String read _nome write _nome;
        property id_cidade : Integer read Get_id_cidade write Set_id_cidade;
  End;
```

//Interface do serviço

```
{ Invokable interface IEmpresa }
unit EmpresaIntf;
interface
uses Soap.InvokeRegistry, System.Types, Soap.XSBuiltIns, System.Generics.Collections, EMPRESA;
type
    { Invokable interfaces must derive from IInvokable }
  IEmpresa = interface(IInvokable)
  ['{D5980639-6211-4748-B065-B7FD7287C7C6}']

    function savePessoa(Pessoa : TPessoa):TPessoa;stdcall;
  end;

implementation

initialization
  { Invokable interfaces must be registered }
  InvRegistry.RegisterInterface(TypeInfo(IEmpresa));

end.
```

Implementação da Interface

```
function TEmpresa.savePessoa(Pessoa: TPessoa): TPessoa;
begin
    Result := Pessoa
end;
```

O teste pode ser feito com o código abaixo (basta salvar em um arquivo .html e abrir no navegador).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="js/funcoes.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function () { 
                $("#btcarregar").click(function() {
                    var envelope = '<?xml version="1.0"?> \
                                    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">\
                                    <SOAP-ENV:Body xmlns:NS1="urn:EmpresaIntf-IEmpresa" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:NS2="urn:EMPRESA">\
                                    <NS1:savePessoa><Pessoa href="#1"/></NS1:savePessoa>\
                                    <NS2:TPESSOA id="1" xsi:type="NS2:TPESSOA">\
                                    <id xsi:type="xsd:int">1</id>\
                                    <Nome xsi:type="xsd:string">Nome de teste</Nome>\
                                    <id_cidade xsi:type="xsd:int">5</id_cidade>\
                                    </NS2:TPESSOA></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>\
                                ';
                    getSOAP(envelope);} 
                    ); 

                $("#btincorreto").click(function() {
                    var envelope = '<?xml version="1.0"?> \
                                    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">\
                                    <SOAP-ENV:Body xmlns:NS1="urn:EmpresaIntf-IEmpresa" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:NS2="urn:EMPRESA">\
                                    <NS1:savePessoa><Pessoa href="#1"/></NS1:savePessoa>\
                                    <NS2:TPESSOA id="1" xsi:type="NS2:TPESSOA">\
                                    <id xsi:type="xsd:int">1</id>\
                                    <Nome xsi:type="xsd:string">Nome de teste</Nome>\
                                    <id_cidade xsi:type="xsd:int"></id_cidade>\
                                    </NS2:TPESSOA></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>\
                                ';
                    getSOAP(envelope);} 
                    );                  
            });


function getSOAP(envelope) {
                    var wsUrl = "http://alexcamilo.no-ip.org:9000/soap/IEMPRESA";
                    $.ajax({
                        url: wsUrl,
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "xml",
                        data: envelope,
                        contentType: "text/plain",
                        cache: false,
//                        complete: endSaveProduct,
                        success: processSuccess,
                        error: processError
                    });                  
                }

function processSuccess(data, status, req){
    $("#resultado").text(data.activeElement.innerHTML);
    }

</script> 
<title>Teste</title>
</head>
</body>
<div>
<input type="button" id="btcarregar">Chamada passando valor</input>
<input type="button" id="btincorreto">Chamada passando vazio</input>
<div>
<div id="resultado" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Posta a parte do código que esta dando o erro!

Comment: Mostra como esta passando os dados amigo!

Comment: Existe algum problema passar como 0 ? Pq converter isso não vai da não ehim (eu acho)

Comment: Não funciona assim: ID_Cidade : Integer=9999; semelhante aos parâmetros de uma classe!?

Comment: O problema de passar como 0(zero) é quando o valor realmente for zero.

Comment: @CelsoMarigoJr,  O delphi aceita declarar uma variável com valor definido somente se for Global! Se o caso dele resolver ele pode sim fazer isto!

Comment: @JúniorMoreira, quis dizer da forma que fazemos uma função, por exemplo: function TfrmPrincipal.LinhaCommand(CodVen, DirArquivos : String; ConsultaPed : String = '' ): String;, neste exemplo o campo ConsultaPed tem por padrão o valor ''. Você quis dizer que isso só é possível no delphi se a variável for global isso?

Comment: @CelsoMarigoJr Não, estou dizendo no caso dele que a Variável é do tipo Integer, e não foi inicializada!

Comment: @Camilassos passa então um valor negativo por Default, passa -1 e vamos ver o resultado, ja que existe a possibilidade de tal ID iniciar com 0!

Comment: @JúniorMoreira, A minha Intenção é disponibilizar esta interface (via wsdl) para qualquer pessoa que queira utilizá-la, ficar livre, para desenvolver um cliente em qualquer linguagem, mas, não ficaria elegante forçar o usuário a informar um valor, quando o campo for nulo.

Comment: @Camilassos,então amigo, mude para String toda estrutura ou coloque -1 como Default como eu falei!

Comment: @JúniorMoreira, Obrigado pela ajuda, mas era burrada minha mesmo, o campo é chave estrangeira, então devo expor a classe da chave estrangeira e não o campo, ai ele poderá se nulo. Obrigadão ai.

Comment: Flw boa sorte!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Embora você não tenha informado como foi definida sua entidade **cidade**, presumo que tenha uma *foreign key* relacionando pessoa x cidade. Se esse for o caso você tera uma violação de chave se tentar inserir valor zero ou que não exista na entidade **cidade**.

Sabemos que o Delphi é fortemente tipado, tipos Integer, Boolean, DateTime.... não podem ser nulos, eles nascem com um valor default.

Existem algumas implementações que possibilitam setar **nil** a um tipo **Integer** por exemplo, se chama **Nullable**.

O projeto [Spring4D](https://bitbucket.org/sglienke/spring4d) traz essa implementação, você pode ter algo como:

```
TObject = class
private
    FQuantity: Nullable<Integer>;
    FDescription: Nullable<string>;
public
    property Quantity: Nullable<Integer> read FQuantity write FQuantity;
    property Description: Nullable<string> read FDescription write FDescription;
end;
```